# Values from Javascript to HTML won't read in the Server Side

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

This is my function for the `onchange` event

Javascript code:

```
 function optionsModel() {
        var x = document.getElementById("model");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        var makeValue = document.getElementById("make").value;
        x.innerHTML = "";
        option.text = "Model";
        x.add(option);
        option.innerHTML = "Model";
        if (makeValue == "ALFA ROMEO") {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = "156";
            x.appendChild(opt);
        }
        else if (makeValue == "AUDI") {
            var audi = ["A3", "A4", "TT"];
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = audi[i];
                opt.innerHTML = audi[i];
                x.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
     }
```

`.aspx` + HTML code:

```
    <body>
  <div class="container form-group">
    <div class="row">
    <form runat="server">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <select class="form-control" name="Make" id="make" runat="server" onchange=" return optionsModel()">
              <option value="select" selected>Select Make</option>
              <option value="ALFA ROMEO">ALFA ROMEO</option>
              <option value="AUDI">AUDI</option>
          </select></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"> <select class="form-control" name="Model" id="model" runat="server">
        <option value="Model">Model</option>
      </select></div>
```

`aspx.cs`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string modelValue = this.model.Value;
            string makeValue = this.make.Value;
         }
```

When i select ALFA ROMEO in the Make Select tag, the Model tag will display the specific options but when i press the button it will give the modelValue a "Model".It means that the values from the JS were not transferred in the server side. How can I get those values on server side?

Comment: You are mixing server and client side code as if they know what the other is doing.  Any changes that you do on client side javascript, that you don't specifically send to the server is lost.  Maybe look at AJAX and do all your option logic on the server.

Comment: that's why. should i use AJAX sir? because i dont know how to do AJAX. im just new in this languages. @AnthonyHorne

Comment: It is very easy to start using, especially though visual studio.  Do a search for Ajax.Net and updatepanel.  There are many, many examples.  You will simply add a scriptmanager on the top of the page and then add an updatepanel around your controls.   Then act on the normal events like dropdown_change(), etc.  As it does partial submits, it is generally quick and the users often doesn't know a server trip is happening.   Also look at progressbar when you do this.

Comment: thank you so much. i will now start reading about ajax since it is so important. thank you for the time. @AnthonyHorne

Comment: Just try to get the difference between Server Side and Client Side code execution model. JavaScript is client side, it executes within the browser context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways :

1. use AJAX if you want to perform asynchronous action, link above will be help (recommended):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquery-ajax-function-call-code-behind-C-Sharp-method/

2. use standard server client request(GET), for example while onchange page will redirect to /index.aspx?makeval="A"&modelval="B"

The Example of ajax is like below :

Client side (aspx)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function optionsModel() {
            var x = document.getElementById("model");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            var makeValue = document.getElementById("make").value;
            x.innerHTML = "";
            option.text = "Model";
            x.add(option);
            option.innerHTML = "Model";
            if (makeValue == "ALFA ROMEO") {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.innerHTML = "156";
                x.appendChild(opt);
            }
            else if (makeValue == "AUDI") {
                var audi = ["A3", "A4", "TT"];
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = audi[i];
                    opt.innerHTML = audi[i];
                    x.appendChild(opt);
                }
            }
        }

        function submit() {

            var makeValue = document.getElementById("make").value
            var modelValue = document.getElementById("model").value;

                         $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "MakeModel.aspx/Submit",
                                data: "{'make':'"+makeValue+"', 'model':'"+modelValue+"'}",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: OnSuccess,
                                error: function(response) {
                                    alert(response);
                                }
                            });
                        }



         function OnSuccess(response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
          <select class="form-control" name="Make" id="make" runat="server" onchange=" return optionsModel()">
              <option value="select">Select Make</option>
              <option value="ALFA ROMEO">ALFA ROMEO</option>
              <option value="AUDI">AUDI</option>
          </select>
          <select class="form-control" name="Model" id="model" runat="server">
            <option value="Model">Model</option>
          </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Procced"  name="submit" onclick="submit()" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Server Side (Aspx.cs)

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Submit(string make,string model)
{
    return make+" "+model;
}
```

In Client side the important javascript function is submit , url is define function in MakeModel.aspx, data is parameter for submit function in server side.

I hope it will help you to understand ajax.

Comment: can you help me constructing the ajax for my code? im so confused about the ajax and jquery. thank you. @DikaArtaKarunia

Comment: thanks, you help me a lot and i now understand ajax a bit thanks. @Dika Arta Karunia